# Configuring Quick Apps in Laragon

Tags: laragon

I'm trying to install both Laravel and jetstream in Laragon by chaining together commands.

I have got as far as this which is successful in as far as the first part runs but nothing after the double ampersand.

```
LaravelJetstreamWithInertia =composer create-project laravel/laravel %s --prefer-dist && composer require laravel/jetstream && php artisan jetstream:install inertia --ssr --dark
```

Can anyone yell me if it is at least possible to chain commands in Laragon's quick app configuration and if so how to do it correctly?